# Simulate cors preflight requests with python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request

I am checking a django-rest-framework with a simple python `requests.post`.

However, the browser of the front-end changes the POST request to an OPTIONS request for doing a CORS preflight. In the django-rest-framework, I use the `corsheaders` app in INSTALLED_APP and several changed settings in `settings.py`.

How can I test these changes and send a `requests.post` with CORS preflight?